# Como realizar a migração do spring security 3.0.5 para o 4.2.3

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring, spring-security

Gostaria de saber como faço para passar do Spring Secuirty 3.0.5 para o 4.2.3

Meu xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher><!-- mandatory to allow the managed bean to forward the request to the filter -->
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Project Stage Level -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- JSF Servlet is defined to container -->
    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Mapping with servlet and url for the http requests. -->
    <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 

    <!-- Welcome Page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Meu root-context.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.slackspace.tutorials.customloginpage" />

</beans>
```

Meu xml do security:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="false">

        <intercept-url pattern="/View/UnSecured/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/View/Secured/user/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_COMMON')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/View/Secured/adm/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/theme/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="Pacotes de Código-fonte/**" access="permitAll"/>

        <!-- Custom login page -->
        <form-login always-use-default-target="true"
                    default-target-url="/View/Secured/user/index.jsf"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?error=true"
                    login-page="/login.jsf"/>

        <!-- Custom logout page -->
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsf" logout-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <!--<password-encoder hash="md5"/> -->
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                               users-by-username-query="xxxxxxxxx"
                               authorities-by-username-query="xxxxxxxx"
            />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
        <beans:property name="url" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="xxxxxxxxxx" />
        <beans:property name="xxxxxx" value="xxxxx" />
        <beans:property name="xxxxxx" value="xxxxx" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Meu servlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Minha classe de aplicação do spring:

```
package de.slackspace.tutorials.customloginpage;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes;

@ManagedBean(name="loginController")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginController implements PhaseListener {

     protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    /**
     *
     * Redirects the login request directly to spring security check.
     * Leave this method as it is to properly support spring security.
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws ServletException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String doLogin() throws ServletException, IOException {
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
                .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

        return null;
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.faces.event.PhaseListener#beforePhase(javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent)
     * 
     * Do something before rendering phase.
     */
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        Exception e = (Exception) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get(
                WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);

        if (e instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
            logger.debug("Found exception in session map: "+e);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(
                    WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, null);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Username or password not valid.", "Username or password not valid"));
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.faces.event.PhaseListener#getPhaseId()
     * 
     * In which phase you want to interfere?
     */
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente , eu não utilizaria mais o XML para configurar e sim anotações.
Segundo ao invés de utilizar o 4 já passe para o 5.

Crie um arquivo de configurações extendendo a classe WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter habilitando o springsecurety com a anotação **@EnableWebSecurity**.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

}
```

Com o método **@Override public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception** você configura as exceções.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/layout/**")
        .antMatchers("/stylesheets/**")
        .antMatchers("/fonts/**")
        .antMatchers("/javascriptsgeral/**")
        .antMatchers("/images/**");
    }

}
```

Com o metodo **@Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception** você faz as demais configurações.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/layout/**")
        .antMatchers("/stylesheets/**")
        .antMatchers("/fonts/**")
        .antMatchers("/javascriptsgeral/**")
        .antMatchers("/images/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("cadastro/novo").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("cadastroestoque/**").hasRole("USUARIO")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(10)
                .expiredUrl("/login")
                .and()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login");
    }

}
```

Existem outras configurações dependendo com qual arquitetura estais utilizando. Se JSF, Spring MVC, Spring Boot....
Contudo espero ter lhe dado um inicio.

Comment: Vou tentar a migração, utilizando o anotações. Ja deu pra dar um norte mesmo.

Comment: Qualquer coisa posta ai